# Changing default favicon in Firefox for sites without them

Tags: firefox, css

Is there a userChrome.css CSS declaration that can be used to change the default favicon in Firefox, specifically for the Bookmarks Library and the Bookmarks Sidebar?

Changing it in the bookmarks toolbar and pop-up menu is trivial.  I'm not interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

Better than manually changing the icon manually, I use [IdentFacvIcon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/identfavicon/). This add-on creates new icons for sites that don't have their own, helping to make shortcuts more easily distinguished.

Comment: Shalom Moishe.  That's a very good extension, but I'm concerned about some of the recent reviews and the fact that it hasn't been updated in over 3 years.  Also, I would like something simpler and lighter weight... just a CSS declaration is all I really need.  I'm just not sure which CSS selector to use.